# How automatically double the number of intervals

Tags: fortran

I want to double a number till 256, and when the program gets 256 make stop but the program that I created not giving me a double from 1 till 256
`````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````
Fortran code

```````````````````````
    program exercise1
    implicit none
    real, external :: f
    real :: h,a,b,prod,integration,summ,p
    integer :: i,j,n
    
        print*, 'Welcome, This program using Composite trapezoid method to calculate the integer'
        print*,    '                          -------- '
        prod=1 
        summ=0
        print*,'Number of intervals ','    The integer value'
        do i=1,258
         n=(prod*i*i) ! Getting number of interval till 256  
         a=-1   ! The Lower limit of the integration 
         b=1    ! The Upper limit of the integration 
         h=(b-a)/n  ! Calculate the delta X
         p=(h/2.)*(f(a)+f(b))     ! Here as we have the whole equation is (h/2)*[f(a)+f(b)+2*sum(Xi) ! So we calculate the first part (h/2)*[f(a)+f(b) and then calculate the anoter part
         summ=summ+h*f(a+i*h)   !h/2 *2* sum[f(Xi)      
         integration = p+summ   !Here the sum the both parts
          if(n == 256) then      !put a limit for the number of interval 
          Stop
          end if
         print*,n,'            -', integration
        enddo
        end
        
        real function f(x)     !the function of the integer
        f=sin(x+1)
        end`
        
        
    ``````````````````````
    the output
    ``````````````````
    
               1   2.72789216    
               4   2.46665454    
               9   2.47777867    
              16   2.49350500    
              25   2.50419927    
              36   2.51126313    
              49   2.51606560    
              64   2.51944780    
              81   2.52190781    
             100   2.52374840    
             121   2.52515912    
             144   2.52626276    
             169   2.52714205    
             196   2.52785373    
             225   2.52843738
```````````````````````

Comment: Please show a complete code - without that we cant say for certain what you are doing wrong (I can guess, but without the whole code I won't be able to say for certain)

Comment: Please show your complete programming including `implicit none` and all variable declarations and their initial values.

Comment: I made edit for the post and it contains the complete code

Comment: Your program does give you numbers from 1 to 256. But when you get the 256, it stops because you requested that it stops. Just move the print before the check. **TLDR: Just move the print before the if.**

Comment: But I want to get number like 2 , 8 , 16 , 32, 64 , 128 , 256 the double but I got 1 , 4, 9 , etc 
do you understand me ?

Answer (score 1):

I think you want powers of: 2**i not squares: i**2. For example:

```
do i = 0,8
  print*, 2**i
enddo
```

gives

```
1
2
4
8
16
32
64
128
256
```

Comment: Yes, Thank you for your help

Answer (score -1):

I was originally voting to close as a typo, but your code maybe indeed does something different.

Your codes makes `n` to be a sequence if integer squares. 1^2, 2^2, 3^2 ... 16^2=256

But you wanted doubling the number, in that case just multiply `n` by 2.

```
n = 1
do i = 1, 10
 
  do what you need
  print *, n

  n = n * 2
end do
```

Comment: Complete program ( ;-) )??

Comment: Just one min, I will try and if it is working well, I will tell you Albert

Comment: @albert I am not going to edit the mess in the question. This should really tell what is wrong and should be changed. Basically, remove the `do what you need`, add `end` and it is actually a complete program. The implicit none and variable declarations can be added when needed.

Comment: @VladimirF It was meant a bit sarcastic, but a `program` statement, `implicit none` and `integer :: i,n` never hurt, although it is pseudo code seen the line "do what you need".